# How do I integrate Gnome applications properly in XFCE?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, themes, xfce, gtk

Recently I've installed Xfce. I had used Xubuntu some time ago and wanted to install it again because of the more extensive possibilities to configurate it. However, now I have one problem: some Gnome applications do not use the XFCE-theme.

On that screenshot you can see that the window on the right is apparently not using the XFCE-theme:

[image: screenshot]

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme doesn't support gtk3. So it's use fallback theme.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I have replaced it with http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php?content=141404. It is working fine now.